# How to duplicate a file in Dired?

Tags: dired, filenames

Let's say I have the following file shown in Windows File Explorer:

[image]

If I enter `C-c C-v` to copy and paste the file, the file is duplicated and automatically given a name:

[image]

We can repeat this to get more duplicates which are also automatically named:

[image]

Does a similar command exist for `dired`? I looked for something like `dired-do-duplicate` but didn't notice anything like that.

Comment: I notice macOS Finder does the similiar, Duplicate menu item uses foo.txt, foo copy.txt, foo copy 2.txt, foo copy 3.txt and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do more or less what you request.

```lisp
(defun dired-duplicate-this-file ()
  "Duplicate file on this line."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((this  (dired-get-filename t))
         (ctr   1)
         (new   (format "%s[%d]" this ctr)))
    (while (file-exists-p new)
      (setq ctr  (1+ ctr)
            new  (format "%s[%d]" this ctr)))
     (dired-copy-file this new nil))
  (revert-buffer))
```

That copies a file `foo` to `foo[1]`, or `foo[2]` if `foo[1]` exists, etc.

If you want a different naming convention, e.g., `foo Copy`, `foo Copy (2)`, etc. then use something like this:

```lisp
(defun dired-duplicate-this-file ()
  "Duplicate file on this line."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((this  (dired-get-filename t))
         (ctr   1)
         (new   (format "%s Copy" this)))
    (while (file-exists-p new)
      (setq ctr  (1+ ctr)
            new  (format "%s Copy (%d)" this ctr)))
     (dired-copy-file this new nil))
  (revert-buffer))
```

Of course, if you duplicate a file such as `foo[2]` or `foo Copy (2)` then you'll get files named like `foo[2][1]`, `foo[2][2]`, ... or `foo Copy (2) Copy`, `foo Copy (2) Copy (2)`, ...

And if your file has an extension, such as `.txt`, then the new name will be something like `foo.txt[1]` or `foo.txt Copy`.  Not sure if that's what you want.  If not, you can use functions `file-name-sans-extension` and `file-name-extension` to move the extension after the number (if that's what you want), so you get `foo[1].txt` or `foo Copy.txt`.  It all depends on what you want.

Function `format` lets you specify the form you want. See `C-h f format` for info.

Comment: That is a very elegant implementation. Thank you Drew!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite easily, and rather more flexibly, without defining any functions (and probably learning another way of using `dired` along the way).

1. Mark the files you want to copy (if no files are marked, operate on the file at point.)
2. "% C" (`dired-do-copy-regexp`)
3. ".*" (copy from regexp) - specify a regexp matching the whole file name
4. "\&-copy" (copy to) - the input file name, plus "-copy"
5. You are shown a preview of the copy operation, which you accept with "y" (or "!" if copying multiple files)

A similar approach allows you to rename files ("% R").

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mikado! This does indeed work, however it's a little bit verbose in terms of keystrokes. This approach seems to take around 16 or so keystrokes.

The idea would be to have something like `C-c C-d` call `dired-duplicate-this-file`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @mikado's answer I've written a simple function that allows the user to specify the suffix to add to the file being copied, while keeping its extension:

```lisp
(defun dired-duplicate-this-file (suffix)
  "Duplicate file on this line."
  (interactive (list (read-string "Suffix: " "_COPY")))
  (dired-do-copy-regexp "\\(.*\\)\\.\\(.*\\)"
                        (concat "\\1" suffix ".\\2"))
  )
```

As any other function, you can invoke it with `M-x dired-duplicate-this-file` while hovering over a file in a `dired` buffer, and you can change the default suffix that appears in the mini-buffer.

For instance, a file named "file.txt" will be copied to a new file named "file_COPY.txt".

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach which is implemented as a keyboard macro

```
(fset 'macro-dired-do-duplicate
      (lambda (&optional arg)
    "Keyboard macro."
    (interactive "p")
    (kmacro-exec-ring-item
     (quote ([up down 67108896 5 134217847 67 25 32 45 32 67 111 112 121 return 121 101 115 return 103] 0 "%d"))
     arg)))
```

If I run this `macro-dired-do-duplicate` on the file `abc.txt` shown below, we get the following:

[image]

Note that this version does not support repeated duplicates.
It would be interesting to see a non-macro function implementation of this.